# I was trying to check if an input is equal to a character in a string

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I tried to find out if an input is a part of the string

```
if my_input==astring[i]:
```

However, python returns me with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Programs/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    if my_input==astring[i]:
builtins.TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: the `i` in you code `astring[i]`, must be integers.please check.

Comment: Where do you define `i`? (code please)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this task:

```
import re

if re.compile(my_input).match(astring):
```

Or, better yet, a simple "in" clause:

```
if my_input in astring:
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is most likely looping through the string so the variable i in the loop would be a character other than an integer. Try something like this:

```
for i in range(0,len(astring)):
if my_input==astring[i]:
    print('input matches charachter')
```

This loops through a list of numbers generated by the range function and then on each number it gets the position of the character in the string.